# Populating a column (z) with data from another column (x) if it's larger than data in another column (y)

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a column based on values in two other columns, and I'm struggling.

I have one df (call it 'alldata') which is the result of merging two dfs. Some IDs appeared in both dfs which has resulted in two year columns in alldata (let's call them yearx and yeary), and some IDs have values in both year columns as they were evaluated for different things at different times. I'm trying to create a final year column (year z) which will take:

- The year from yearx when that ID only has a value in yearx and not in yeary also.
- The year from yeary when that ID only has a value in yeary and not in yearx also
- Where there's a value in year x and year y, I want to take the most recent year.

Simplified example of what I want the end result to be:

```
  ID  "Year x"  "Year y" "Year z"  
  1   2008      2003    2008
  2   2018      2011    2018
  3   NA        2020    2020
  4   NA        2015    2015
  5   2017      2012    2017
  6   NA        2017    2017
```

I've tried using `ifelse` and `which` and I can't get it to work - I'm still fairly new to R so I think I just can't get my head around how to use it properly.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alldata$yearz <- max(alldata$yearx, alldata$yeary, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't heard of max, so I'd never have got this. I had to use pmax - max gave me a column full of '2020'.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it worked so that others can see that and can stop looking.